# How do I pass a variable into grails template from a Layout file?

Tags: grails, layout, templates

So I have a navigation template (/common/_navigation.gsp) that is getting rendered in the Grails projects main Layout file (/layouts/main.gsp).  How do I pass some kind of variable/parameter/arg from the individual view files to layout and eventually into the navigation template?  I just want the right tab to be highlighted when I'm on a page.

(We've already tried using the Grails Navigation Plugin.  Since we have different tabs that point to the same controllers (same view, different filter) it breaks down.)

Comment: Lee,

I was trying to use a solution that I found here: http://blog.openmind.ws/2009/06/10/grails-layouts-with-sitemesh/

Where I declare a page name using a parameter tag and then call that in a pageproperty in the layout.

But that pageproperty wasn't working for me.  I read somewhere that pageproperty doesn't work well in grails 1.2m3.  I'm already on m4 so that might be what's causing my headaches.

Answer (score 21):

I do this pattern all the time.  In my view, I can attach a property to the page either manually or by using the parameter tag in the view that I'm rendering.  Its not documented in the Grails user guide, but its super handy.

```
<parameter name="foo" value="bar" />
```

Then I would access the page property by using the [pageProperty tag](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tags/pageProperty.html).

```
<g:set var="activeNavItem" value="${pageProperty(name: 'page.foo')}"/>
```

The layout doesn't need to handle this variable at all :-)

Comment: I already use this tag but I'm astonished to not find it mentionned anywhere? Have you some clues on the subject and how did you find it?

Comment: PomCompot: I first found out about it a *long* time ago.  I had to dig around the source code to find out where it actually does its work. Its a lower level Sitemesh mapping.

Comment: The pattern is found in: SitemeshPreprocessor.java

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Will look at this in detail.

Answer (score 20):

just use the model parameter
for Example:
view:

```
<g:render template="../path/template" model="[header:'test', headers:['a','b'], values:[['a':1,'b':2],['a':3,'b':4]] ]"/>
```

_template:

```
<br/>
    <h3>${header}</h3>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <g:each in ="${headers}" var="he">
            <th>${he}</th>
          </g:each>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <g:each in ="${values}" var="v">
              <tr>
                <g:each in ="${headers}" var="h">
                  <td>${v[h]}</td>
                </g:each>
              </tr>
          </g:each>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: This only answers how to pass variables down to a template, not up to the layout. IMO, this is the cleanest way to pass down to templates, though.

Comment: @Wonko why would anyone want to pass a variable up to the main template?

Answer (score 15):

I use an arguably simpler method.  Just define a variable at request scope in the individual view before you call your layout.  It will be available in all templates used in the request, including the layout and any called via `<g:render>`

```
<g:set var="SOMEVARIABLE" value="SOMEVALUE" scope="request"/>
<meta name="layout" content="yourlayout">
```

Then just reference the variable as you would any other in your layout or other templates pulled in by your view

```
${SOMEVARIABLE}  or <g:if test="${SOMEVARIABLE}">, etc., etc
```

Comment: This seems a more general solution, as this way, you can pass any kind of variables (arrays, maps etc.). The pageProperty pattern seems only to work with strings. Note that it is not necessary that the set-tag is _before_ the meta-tag (or even that the meta tag is present).

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to use a page property: http://grails.org/doc/1.1.1/ref/Tags/pageProperty.html

Then pass it into the render tag using the model param.

cheers

Lee

Answer (score 1):

The pattern I like, uses the pageProperty as follows. In the layout, I reference the pageProperty like so:

**The layout gsp**

```
<body id="${pageProperty(name: 'page.pageType')}">
    <g:render template="/layouts/header" />
    <g:layoutBody/>
    <g:render template="/layouts/copyright" />
</div>
```

... and within the `<head>` section of the specific gsp page (I found that it did NOT work outside the head section), I declare the value like so:

**The page gsp**

```
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
    <parameter name="pageType" value="homePg" />
</head>
```

**Resulting HTML**

```
<body id="homePg">
    ... header, body and footer ...
</body>
```

In addition, I can inject a value from the controller model into pageProperty like so:

**Controller**

```
def index() {
    model: [modelPageType: 'adminPg']
}
```

**The layout gsp (using the same layout as above)**

```
<body id="${pageProperty(name: 'page.pageType')}">
    <g:render template="/layouts/header" />
    <g:layoutBody/>
    <g:render template="/layouts/copyright" />
</div>
```

**The page gsp**

```
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
    <parameter name="pageType" value="${modelPageType}" />
</head>
```

**Resulting HTML**

```
<body id="adminPg">
    ... header, body and footer ...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply reach any variable in any template in the page by getting it from params.
Just type `${params.variable}` in layout and you will get your variable.

Answer (score -3):

Based on my readings, I think its not a good practice to pass variables to your layout. Model variables are accessible in your view. I think layouts should be used only to specify the structure of the page while views can be used to fill in the content.

Comment: Downvoted as not accurate. The question is not if it is good or bad practice but how to do this. Would better fit in a question comment than in an answer.