# Can a Grails Layout call a template?

Tags: templates, grails, layout

I want my main layout to conditionally put in some blocks of html that I want to be defined in a separate file.

I have more than one kind of navigation bar defined.  I want to have a file for each navigation bar.  Then I want to just set a variable in my controller or specific gsp file so that the layout chooses which navigator to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can accomplish this in a few different ways.  The first way that I'd suggest trying having something like this in your layout:

```
<g:if test="${nav == 'nav1'}">
     <g:render template="/nav/nav1" />
</g:if>
<g:elseif test="${nav == 'nav2'}">
     <g:render template="/nav/nav2" />
</g:elseif>
<g:else>
     <g:render template="/nav/default" />
</g:else>
```

In order for those templates to be rendered, you must have the following files:

- `grails-app/views/nav/_nav1.gsp`
- `grails-app/views/nav/_nav2.gsp`
- `grails-app/views/nav/_default.gsp`

Notice that because the template is 'root-relative' that it resolved the template from the root of the `grails-app/views` directory. See the [user guide section on Views and Templates](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.2.3%20Views%20and%20Templates) for more.

Another method would be to dynamically render the navigation based on a parameter like this (in your Layout):

```
<g:render template="/nav/${nav ?: 'default'}" />
```

or if you want to go down the rabbit hole a little more, you could do something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829318/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-into-grails-template-from-a-layout-file/1876881#1876881).

If you are still running into issues, then I'd imagine that there is something else that has been missed like passing some model parameters to the [render tag](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/render.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to put conditions around g:render statements.  You can either do

```
<% if (condition) { %>
 <g:render template="/common/topbar" />
<% } %>
```

or

```
<g:if test="yourcondition">
 <g:render template="/common/topbar" />

</g:if>
```

Comment: Hello Jean,  I had problems using render inside of a layout.  They worked great inside of a regular gsp.  They came out unexecuted when they were part of a layout.